# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь спарсить ссылку из тега img, но выдает ошибку:

**"image":block.find("img", class_="load_image load_done").get("src")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'**

Помогите,пожалуйста.

```
for block in blocks:
    cards.append(
    {
        "title":block.find("a").text,
        "link":block.find("a").get("href"),
        "bank":block.find_all("span")[0].text,
        "pay_system":block.find_all("span")[1].text,
        "bet":block.find("div", class_="card-v2__text-accent").text,
        
        "image":block.find("img", class_="load_image load_done").get("src")
        
    }
)
```

Comment: Нету значит там такой картинки :`block.find("img", class_="load_image load_done")`.

Comment: <img class="load_image load_done" 
src="https://admin.myfin.by/images/kart_images/visa-gold-br-1.png" alt="Кредитная карта R-Кредитка от Банка Решение" data-url-img="https://admin.myfin.by/images/kart_images/visa-gold-br-1.png">

Вот код картинки, подскажите , пожалуйста, как достать ее ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Если открыть исходник страницы, то там обнаруживается совсем другой тег:

```
<img class="load_image" src="/images/new/img_preloader_logo.svg" alt="Кредитная карта R-Кредитка от Банка Решение" data-url-img="https://admin.myfin.by/images/kart_images/visa-gold-br-1.png">
```

А вот в инспекторе уже совсем другое:

```
<img class="load_image load_done" src="https://admin.myfin.by/images/kart_images/visa-gold-br-1.png" alt="Кредитная карта R-Кредитка от Банка Решение" data-url-img="https://admin.myfin.by/images/kart_images/visa-gold-br-1.png">
```

Отсюда как бы напрашивается вывод о динамической подгрузке картинок, и искать надо по первому варианту (и смотреть атрибут `data-url-img`). Да и имя класса `load_done` как бы намекает, что он устанавливается у картинок у которых "загрузка завершена".